# Linq spit numeric list in search (kentico)

Tags: c#, linq, kentico

In kentico the standard way to get documents in below (which I believe is based on ObjectQuery and has linq commands). Im trying to filter it by one more field "newsCategory" which contains data like "1|2|3". So I cant add     .Search("newsCategory", 1) etc because I need to split the list before I can search it. What direction should I be looking? A select sub-query? (Im new to linq)

```
// Get documents
var news = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("CMS.News")
.OnSite("CorporateSite")
.Path("/News", PathTypeEnum.Children)
.Culture("en-us")
.CombineWithDefaultCulture(false);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data?

Comment: newsCategory = "1|2|3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as this is a field from the coupled table, you can't access it through property, but have to use `GetValue()` instead. Once you've got, you can work with it like with regular string:

```
var news = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("CMS.News")
            .OnSite("CorporateSite")
            .Path("/News", PathTypeEnum.Children)
            .Culture("en-us")
            .CombineWithDefaultCulture(false)
            .Where(d => d.GetStringValue("newsCategory","").Split('|').Contains("1"));
```

Comment: I believe `.Equals()` would be better than `.Contains()`.

Comment: @rocky Split() returns an array, but we need to check if array contains a particular value, if I'm nor mistaken.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Ignore my comment :D my hands were faster than my brain

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your data is 1|2|3   and not 1|2|3|  or |1|2|3  ?

If it is, you could do  `.Where("NewsCategory", QueryOperator.Like,  "%" + id + "|%")`

Otherwise you may have to get back more results, and then loop through them and split the values to find the exact one you want.

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt have delimiter at start or end. Could it be done with regex?

Comment: The document query basically creates a sql query, and I am not sure how you would do this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**  Check out [this article](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/kentico-8-technology-dataquery-api) that shows some more advanced where commands you can use with the Data Query API.  You should be able to MacGyver a proper filter with those options.

<strike>I believe you're looking for:</strike>

```
.WhereLike("DocumentCategoryID", "CategoryID");
//OR
.WhereLike("DocumentCategory","CategoryName");
```

I don't have v8 installed to double check which exact key/value pair to filter by, but according to [this Document Query API article](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/kentico-8-technology-documentquery-api) you filter document sets with the WhereLike() method.

According to the [API documentation](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_0/api/html/M_CMS_DocumentEngine_DocumentHelper_GetDocuments.htm), GetDocuments() returns a [`MultiDocumentQuery` object](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_0/api/html/T_CMS_DocumentEngine_MultiDocumentQuery.htm).  I'm not 100% certain if that implements `IEnumerable`, so you may not even be able to use LINQ with it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe something like this would work.  There is a wherein property that should be able to pull the value out.  Not exactly sure how it would handle the scenario of having a 1 and then an 11, but it may be work looking into.

```
// Get documents
var news = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("CMS.News")
.OnSite("CorporateSite")
.Path("/News", PathTypeEnum.Children)
.Culture("en-us")
.CombineWithDefaultCulture(false)
.WhereIn("NewsCategory",1);
```

Comment: Yes, thought of this but a like is going to find everything with a 1 as you mentioned